# Select id with unique value

Tags: sql

```
+----+--------+-----------+
| ID | ID_DEP | OPERATION |
+----+--------+-----------+
|  1 |      2 | T1        |
|  2 |      2 | T1        |
|  3 |      2 | T4        |
|  4 |      1 | T1        |
|  5 |      1 | T1        |
|  6 |      1 | T4        |
|  7 |      4 | T6        |
|  8 |      3 | T1        |
|  9 |      3 | T1        |
| 10 |      5 | T9        |
+----+--------+-----------+
```

Hey guys, help me with that simple question.

How to select only these id's (ID_DEP) that have ONLY T1 from Operation column and not other value.

Comment: What have you tried already? What, exactly, are you stuck on?

Comment: Select ID_DEP from TABLE where OPERATION = 'T1'

I need too see id with the T1 and no other operation.

Comment: `NOT EXISTS(correlated  subquery on same table)`

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT ID_DEP FROM table WHERE Operation = 'T1'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a `WHERE NOT EXISTS`

Test Data

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TestData
CREATE TABLE #TestData (ID int, ID_DEP int, OPERATION varchar(2))
INSERT INTO #TestData (ID, ID_DEP, OPERATION)
VALUES
 (1,2,'T1')
,(2,2,'T1')
,(3,2,'T4')
,(4,1,'T1')
,(5,1,'T1')
,(6,1,'T4')
,(7,4,'T6')
,(8,3,'T1')
,(9,3,'T1')
,(10,5,'T9')
```

Query

```
SELECT
td.*
FROM #TestData td
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #TestData sub WHERE sub.OPERATION <> 'T1' AND td.ID_DEP = sub.ID_DEP)
```

Output

```
ID  ID_DEP  OPERATION
8   3       T1
9   3       T1
```

Basically, the `NOT EXISTS` returns any rows where the value `IS NOT` 'T1'. If an `ID_DEP` exists then we want to exclude this from the result set.